# Playing Local MP3 Android - Cordova "Media Undefined"

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm building an app using PhoneGap/Cordova that is to play an mp3 file in the background. I have added the Cordova Media plugin, but when I test in my browser I'm getting "Media" undefined as if it can't find the plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var bgMedia = new Media( getPhoneGapPath('timer') );
   bgMedia.play();  

    function getPhoneGapPath(audiofile) {

      var path = window.location.pathname;
          path = path.substr( path, path.length - 23 );
          path = path + 'audio/'+audiofile+'.mp3';
      return 'file://' + path;
     }
});
```

I have confirmed that the path is correct for the file. My question is twofold, how do I get the Media plugin configured properly to actually worse (am I missing another step) and what is the proper way to call and play the file?

Using current version of Cordova.

Comment: Did you installed the plugin?

Comment: Yes my post indicates that I have.

Answer (score 3):

After some digging I was able to make the following work:

```html
// Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            playAudio();   
        }

        // Audio player
        //
        var my_media = null;
        var mediaTimer = null;

         function getCordovaPath() {

            var path = window.location.pathname;
   if (device.platform == "Android") {
      path = "/android_asset/www/";
   } 
   // path = cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/'
           // path = path.substr( path, path.length - 23 );

            //path = path + 'audio/'+audiofile+'.mp3';
            return 'file://' + path;
        }

        // Play audio
        //
        function playAudio() {
            // Create Media object from src
            //my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
            my_media = new Media(getCordovaPath() + 'audio/timer.mp3',
          // success callback
          function () { console.log("playAudio():Audio Success"); },
          // error callback
          function (err) { console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err); });

            // Play audio
            my_media.play();

           
        }

        // Pause audio
        //
        function pauseAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.pause();
            }
        }

        // Stop audio
        //
        function stopAudio() {
            if (my_media) {
                my_media.stop();
            }
        }

        // onSuccess Callback
        //
        function onSuccess() {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        }

        // onError Callback
        //
        function onError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                  'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        // Set audio position
        //
        function setAudioPosition(position) {
            document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
        }
```

Comment: can you tell me how was the folder structure, where you placed timer.mp3?

Comment: I am able to play mp3 files over internet URL. `http://test.com/test.mp3` but I want to play local mp3 files created at runtime. I can save audiocontent from Google TTS and decode/save it as mp3 using the cordova file plugin. I save my file in the cache folder, e.g. `file:///data/user/0/my.domain/cache/test.mp3` but I get `error code 1` when I play it with the media plugin The file is there on the device because I can read it and get the binary content.

Comment: Never mind, it is working! I did not correctly decode and save base64 data. My local generated mp3 files are playing with cordova media plugin using the file location starting with `file:///data/user/0/xxxxxxxxx/.....`

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugins works only on devices or emulators. 
If you run the project in the browser you need to mock them to prevent that the app crash.

When I run the project in the browser I uncomment this line from index.html:

```
<script src="js/mocks/plugin.media.js"></script>
```

plugin.media.js:

```
window.Media = {
  get: function(){},
  play: function(){},
  stop: function(){},
  seekTo: function(){},
  pause: function(){},
  getDuration: function(){},
  getCurrentPosition: function(){},
  startRecord: function(){},
  stopRecord: function(){},
  release: function(){},
  setVolume: function(){},
  onStatus: function(){}
};
```

Comment: I don't have that js file in my directory. In addition, when I compile and run on my devices (iPad and Galaxy Tab 3) it fails as well.

Comment: You need to create this file if you want [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) the Media plugin. When run on devices what error are you receiving?